# Parsing Injected Web Page Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xhtml

Trying to create an iPhone app (Objective-C) for my school.  I want it to search for, and then parse any emergency announcements on the web page.  They do not occur in the HTML, and are probably written in with PHP or another server-sire language.  Any way i can access that information? (Link: http://www.ridgefield.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you parse `http://www.ridgefield.org/ajax/dist/emergency-announcements` as this is the address where the website fetches the info.

Next time you could use the Firefox plugin Tamper Data found at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/. Try it out!

Comment: thank you! i'm not sure how you found that page, but it is perfect.